# Lefschetz duality for non-compact relative manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I'd like to use the formulation of Lefschetz duality stated [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lefschetz_duality), but I can't seem to find a reference for this particular version of it, and it doesn't seem quite right to me.

The exact statement in question is:
Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space, and let $A \subset X$ be a subspace such that the complement $X - A$ is an orientable topological $n$-manifold. Then, for any abelian group $G$ and any $i$,
$$H_i(X, A; G) \cong H_c^{n - i}(X - A; G),$$
where $H_i$ and $H_c^{n - i}$ denote singular homology and compactly supported singular cohomology, respectively.

The problem is, by Poincaré duality, $H_c^{n - i}(X - A; G) \cong H_i(X - A; G)$, so if the above statement is true, then $H_i(X - A; G) \cong H_i(X, A; G)$. But that definitely doesn't seem right; for example, if $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A = \{(0, 0)\}$, then $H_1(X - A; G) \cong G$ because $X - A$ is homotopic to a circle, but $H_1(X, A; G) \cong \tilde{H}_1(X; G) = 0$.

Is the above statement true in this generality? If so, where can I find a proof, and where is my attempt at a counterexample mistaken? If not, what's the correct formulation?

(The main case I'm interested in is where $X$ is a complex projective variety and $A$ is a closed subvariety containing the singular locus of $X$.)

Comment: I woke up in the middle of the night randomly and I'm too tired to actually think but to apply Poincare duality in the form you did you need a compact manifold, don't you?  Have you looked in Hatcher?  I believe he has a statement about Lefschetz duality but I'm not sure it's the same as this one.  I am also interested in an answer to your question by the way.

Comment: The website says that the statement is in S. Lefschetz, "Manifolds with a boundary and their transformations" Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. , 29 (1927) pp. 429–462.  I'm not sure how easy it would be to get your hands on that.

Comment: @Seth: Poincaré duality works fine here; to use Poincaré duality for a non-compact oriented manifold, you just need to replace cohomology with compactly supported cohomology. (This is Theorem 3.35 in Hatcher.) As for the paper of Lefschetz, I have a copy of that, but it only seems to deal with the case of manifolds with boundary, so I don't see how to extract the statement I described from it (though I could have missed something — it's written in fairly old-fashioned language).

Comment: FYI [the article in question is available freely here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1927-029-02/S0002-9947-1927-1501397-1/home.html).

Comment: I guess that version of Poincare duality follows from Lefschetz duality as stated.  I can't find anything wrong with what you said so I'm confused.

Comment: I spoke to my professor today and he showed me page 297 of Spanier where we have the following: A pair $(X,A)$ is a compact pair if $X$ is compact and $A$ is closed in $X$.  A pair $(X,A)$ is a relative $n$-manifold if $X$ is Hausdorff, $A$ is closed in $X$ and $X \setminus A$ is an $n$-manifold.  Let $(X,A)$ be a compact relative $n$-manifold with $X \setminus A$ oriented.  Then $H_q(X \setminus A;G)\cong H^{n-q}(X,A;G)$.

Comment: In the book there is a bar over cohomology (not sure what that means) but apparently that doesn't matter in this case.  I'll try to understand this better.  The statement is almost what we want except homology and cohomology are switched.

Comment: The conversation with my professor was pressed for time but he said something about using the universal coefficient theorem to get the statement we want.  I'm kind of confused about that right now.  Anyways I hope this helps, let me know if you figure things out.

Comment: Ah, the bar is Alexander cohomology.

Comment: I'm aware of the version of Lefschetz duality on p. 297 of Spanier. However, as you noted, that's not quite the version of the statement I'm interested in, and I don't see how one would follow from the other.

Comment: I think applying the universal coefficient to both sides gives what we want if coefficients are over a field.  But I don't know about where coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$ or an arbitrary abelian group.

Comment: Well I don't have a complete answer but I think I can at least get a statement sufficient to prove the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem as in Milnor.  Is this of interest to you or do you only care about the full result?

Comment: I'm interested in using Lefschetz duality itself, because the variety whose homology I'm trying to compute occurs as an open subvariety of a projective variety whose low-degree homology is already known.

Comment: Why don't you ask on math overflow?

Comment: Good idea. I just posted it there.